# Altering a json feed response - remove a level

Tags: javascript, xml, arrays, json

I am getting the following response from json call

```
[
   {
      'test':{
         'key1':'value',
         'key2':'value'
      }
   }
]
```

can I remove the 'test' level so it becomes:

```
[
  {
    'key1' : 'value', 
    'key2': 'value'
  }
]
```

How do i remove the first level of the json object? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have the parsed json in an object called `result`

```
result = result.map(function (x) {
  return x.test;
});
```

Comment: Thanks.I tried it, but it looks like it not returning back from the function.. here's the snippet of code:json_feed='http://www.***.onlinehome.us/kruger/web/api/twitter/get-tweets1.1.php';
  
    $.getJSON(json_feed, 
        function(feeds) {   
  feeds = feeds.map(function (x) {
   return x.statuses;
  });
  
  alert('hello'); ... it never hits the hello block :(

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Is feeds just undefined or what?

Comment: By the way you should really read up on debugging javascript using for example Chrome. It's way better than inserting a bunch of alerts everywhere. See https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: It does not even step into the feeds.map function.. and does not return out of the call. All lines after this dont seem to get executed.

Comment: yes, when i print out the feeds object (before it enters this function) it displays the parsed variable correctly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43854/discussion-between-hugo-tunius-and-chicagodude)